# Saving a file locally in Firefox, how to set the file type from .part to [.pdf | .doc | .txt ,etc ]

Tags: firefox, save, savefiledialog

I have generated content in the browser and would like to save that content to a file on the user's system as a PDF, DOC, or TXT file.  I would like to prompt the user with the "open" / "save as" dialog box, and have Firefox identify the proper application/file type.

My progress so far: I am able to prompt the user to save the file locally but I am unable to set the file name and application/file type in the dialog box.  Firefox is setting the file extension to ".part", file name appears to be the first 20+ characters of file data, and the application/file type is set to data stream.  How can I set the file name and application type in FF (and in IE as well.)

Thanks
-ven

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language you are using, Im pretty sure its not C#.

Nevertheless, in C#, the open/save file dialoug has a Filter option which allows which file extensions can be used...
Is this HTML your using?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I am using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox will pick up the file name from the `Content-Disposition:` header and the type from the `Content-Type:` header.